# sending data to a django server

Tags: django, socket.io

I'm building a very simple django server and I want to be able to send data to the server which includes timestamps from the client. For that I used a simple AJAX jQuery and the code looks something like that:

```
while (count < 5) {
     current = performance.now() - start;
            if (prev != current) {
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "measure",
                    data : {
                        time : current,
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken : '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    }
                });
                prev = current;
                ++count;
            }
}
```

now this works, but not working fast enough (at least on firefox where the high performance timer is better). When I tried using django-socketio and send the timestamps over the websocket - it worked perfectly, but I find that quite an overkill for what I'm trying to achieve.

Does anyone know a different way to use sockets in django or have another idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did u ever tried this on production enviroment?(Gunicorn, apache etc.) I think production enviroment will solve your performance problem because django test server is for testing your code, not for stress tests (:

Comment: I'll try it. You think the ajax requests in production env should be faster?

Comment: I hope so.I didnt faced with this problem before but most of my performance issues resolved on production enviroment.